# Allow S7 to draw >500mA

Tags: usb, charging, macos

I have a MacBook Pro - as we know, a USB 3 port can output at least 900mA at 5V for 4.5 Watts. 
However, when I plug in my S7, it only draws 500mA. What is the trick to allowing a device to draw 1A? Is it shorting the data pins, or is it a move by Apple to only provide extra current to their own products?

Many Thanks.

Comment: You could try using a *no data or charge only cable*.  Mixed results -YMMV

Comment: Maybe if you build custom kernel with module "usb fast charging" enabled/added.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the S7 itself comes with USB 2.0 as of [official specs](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/galaxy-s7/#!/spec), which allows [0.5A max current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB).

Comment: The extra pins are solely for data - there are five extra pins; two for data in, two for data out, and one for ground. The power pins remain the same between the USB generations. The amount of power drawn is regulated by the phone as well as the computer, which regulates the maximum power provided along the bus :)

Comment: My bad, edited. I'm not actually knowledgable in USB and stuff, just speaking out of what I knew. The 1st part remains valid then, I reckon?